# NSDictionaryM componentsSeparatedByString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to iOS programming and am getting the above error when I convert a key value to a string and then try and parse that string value.

```
NSString *userID = [whoIs objectForKey:@"d"];

NSArray *components = [[NSArray alloc]init];

components = [userID componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
NSString *ID = (NSString*) [components objectAtIndex:1];
```

The NSLOG value for the strings prints out successfully but I cannot seem to parse the value and pass that new value to a different string.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

thank you.

Comment: **Not a question a professional or enthusiast programmer would ask**. By simply reading the error message you will get enough information to successfully debug and eliminate the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means `userID` is an `NSDictionary` not an `NSString`.  I'm guessing you're confused by the output that you see when you `NSLog` a dictionary which is a string that is created by calling `description` on the dictionary.

It looks like you're trying to get the value for a key inside the dictionary so you probably want something like this:

```
NSDictionary *dict = whoIs[@"d"]; // shorthand for [whoIs objectForKey:@"d"]
NSString *userID = dict[@"ID"];
```

Replace the `@"ID"` with whatever the actual name of the key is in your dictionary.